# How to force VisualStudio to select the entire jQuery variable ($myVar) on double click

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2008, autohotkey

I would like to know how to force visual studio 2008 to select the entire variable name when using the jQuery variable standard.

Ex : 
$myVar = $("#MyDiv");

When you double click on "myVar", Visual Studio will only select "myVar" without the "$".

I'm using autoHotkey for my shortcut and I was wondering too if its possible to use it to do that job because Visual Studio is not the only software to work that way. NotePadd++ and Winmerge are doing the same thing.

Comment: Not selecting `$` seems to be the correct behaviour. Yes is it possible using autohotkey, if you adhere to certain restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script defines the middle mouse button as a hotkey that extends the selection one character to the left. It exploits the fact that double clicking on an item sets the cursor to the beginning to the item, when you move left.

```
MButton:: 
tmpClip := Clipboard
Click, 2
Send, ^c
ClipWait
Length := StrLen(Clipboard) + 1
SendInput, {Left 2}{Shift down}
SendStr := "{right" . Length . "}"    
SendInput, %SendStr%{Shift Up}
Clipboard := tmpClip  
return
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do in situations like that is to create a special "Paste" command.

E.g. in ahk I use this:

```
^5:: ; [Ctrl]+[%] will give me %ClipBoard% instead of just ClipBoard
SendInput, `%^v`%
Return
```

This way, **I** decide in which form the clipboard is being pasted.

You could do the same with jQuery variables:

```
^4:: ; [Ctrl]+[$] will give me $ClipBoard instead of just ClipBoard
SendInput, $^v
Return
```

Else you would have to make the script more intelligent and check the character before the selected word and respond differently based on that.

Comment: I was asking for a way to select the variable not to copy it. Great idea by the way but that's not what i want to do !